# JQUERYUI- Close modal dialog when an image is clicked on

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently using the Modal Dialog from jQuery UI as a menu.
The menu consists of some images which when clicked on function as menu items.
The site uses dynamic ajax content to load the pages that are requested. So heres my question:
How to close the modal dialog once a image is clicked on?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
$('<your image>').click(function(){
    $('<your dialog>').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: How can I apply this to many different images? Since I have many images in different modal dialogs acting as the menu.

Comment: @Malmoc you can define all images a class, then use this class as a selector for `click`

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();


<img src='..' class='image_menu'>
<img src='...' class='image_menu'>



$('.image_menu').click(function(){
   $('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the image is loaded (so either in the AJAX callback, or the document being loaded):

```
$('yourImage').click(function(){
   $('yourDialog').dialog('close');
});
```

For multiple images, use a `class` selector (http://api.jquery.com/class-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your image has an id `myImage`, then the below will close the dialog:

```
$("#myImage").on('click', function() {
  $('#divForDialog')dialog("close") 
});
```

*Explanation*: Use of `on` will ensure that the selector for `#myImage` is enforced, even if the images are ajaxed in later, after the page has loaded.

As others have pointed out, if you have several images, then use a css class to identify them and a `.class` jQuery selector.